# Update doesnt work with condition

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update BudCustomers.ImportedRecord Column and BudCustomers.STATUSID Column. The data for these two columns are 1 and 1. so i am trying to update to 0 for both but that doesnt work with this below query

```
   --Update into BudCustomers from Bulk
Update BudCustomers
 set    BudCustomers.ImportedRecord = 0
       ,BudCustomers.VersionID = 1
       ,BudCustomers.STATUSID = 0
       ,BudCustomers.LastModifiedUserID = 'Import'
       ,BudCustomers.LastModifiedDate = GETDATE()
FROM BudCustomers BCUST WITH(NOLOCK)
Where ((BCUST.STATUSID <> 1)
    OR (BCUST.ImportedRecord <> 1)) AND BCUST.LegalName = 'Test, LTD. (1000)'
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "doesn't work" but you have a MAJOR problem here. You really need to get out of the habit of littering your database with NOLOCK. And when used in an update like this it can actually corrupt your indexes. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3172/avoid-using-nolock-on-sql-server-update-and-delete-statements/

Comment: Are you saying the existing data is 1 for both columns? Your where predicates say where it isn't 1 so that would not update those rows because it is explicitly stated not too.

Comment: @SeanLange any suggestions

Comment: Rewrite the where clause to be what you really meant?

Comment: that's correct @JBKing

Comment: So then try `Where (BCUST.STATUSID = 1)
    AND (BCUST.ImportedRecord = 1)) AND BCUST.LegalName = 'Test, LTD. (1000)'` and it should work fine for changing the case where the data are both 1s.

Comment: user - your problem description says "the data for these columns are 1 and 1".  You want to update them to 0.  Your where clause says "the data for one of these or both are not 1".  So you need to change your query to match your problem description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description this is probably what you want.

```
Update BudCustomers
set ImportedRecord = 0
    , VersionID = 1
    , STATUSID = 0
    , LastModifiedUserID = 'Import'
    , LastModifiedDate = GETDATE()
Where 
(
    STATUSID = 1 
    OR
    ImportedRecord = 1
) 
AND LegalName = 'Test, LTD. (1000)'
```